# What is the best way to get access token from cookie and save it in store in Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia, nuxt3

When app is starting I want to get access token from cookie and after save it in store. I use Pinia.

In which place can I do it?

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve and why you would want to store the cookie in the store?

Comment: I store my access token in Pinia but (of course) it clears when i refresh page (for example). So I need have a place to store token (cookie). And when app starts I need get token from cookie and save in Pinia

Comment: I think about plugin or middleware

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, what you are trying to achieve is a refresh access token? Every time you access the protected pages/routes, a new access token will be generated. Is that correct?

Comment: No, i just always need access token in pinia

Answer (score 1):

To retrive the access token from the cookie - [useCookie](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie)

```
const token = useCookie('access-token')
```

Now you can read cookie like this

```
const accessToken = token.value;
```

If you need it to happen on every page, use your [App.vue](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/app) for example to init your custom store and [Pinia actions](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html) to change the value to your needs.